# Angular: Print variable inside another

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a variable `{{type}}` that I want to pass to another field called `{{"SUB-MENU-PLACES.{{type}}"}}`.
But if I write that, what I get is an error, and I don't known how to print that certain variable inside another variable.

[image]

How to print that variable correctly on my HTML?

Comment: I changed your image to an actual image, so that we could see it.  But posting images of code is not ideal.  Read [ask] which states specifically **"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
{{ SUB-MENU-PLACES[beach] | translate }}
```

Use the square brackets property accessor instead of the dot property accessor.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer... The variable `type` is not even used in this. Neither can it get compiled because there is no string to use for the `translate` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do it is not a good practice, but i think this is what you asked for:

```html
{{ 'SUB-MENU-PLACES.' + type | translate }}
```

For this to work the translation key `SUB-MENU-PLACES.beach` has to exist in your translation file of course.